# In symfony forms how I can validate a field (i.e. password) querying the db for the right value?

Tags: php, symfony1, validation, symfony-forms

Newbie question.

I've created a very simple LoginForm class in symfony. It checks if the user inserts the username and the password in the field and It work as expected.

```
// UserLoginForm :: configure()

$this->setWidgets(array(
  'username' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'password' => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(),
));
$this->setValidators(array(
  'username' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true),
  'password' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)
));


// Action :: executeLogin()

$this->loginForm = new UserLoginForm();

if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    $params = $request->getParameter('login');
    $this->loginForm->bind($request->getParameter('login'));

    if ($this->loginForm->isValid()) {
        // ... more code                
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to check the presence of the username field in the db and if it does not exists, I want to **invalidate the form**. The same for the password: if the username + password pair doesn't exist, but with a different message.

Trying to find the solution I searched in two possible ways:

**In the action :**

- querying the db,
- check the username,
- invalidate the form username field (I want the error message in the resulting HTML),
- same for the username + password check

In this case how I can invalidate the form ? 
How to handle the error message in the template ?

**In the form class calling the isValid() method :**

- add *something* to the setValidator()
- OR add a post validator that call a private function which query the model

In this case how can I use the model in the Form class ?

Which is the best/fast approach ?
Other possibilities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be very useful to you to look at the code of the validator of [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/lib/validator/sfGuardValidatorUser.class.php). They create that post validator, and [set it in the form](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/lib/form/doctrine/base/BasesfGuardFormSignin.class.php). Even if you don't want to use sfDoctrineGuardPlugin (or sfGuardPlugin if you use Propel) its code can be a valuable source of inspiration.

Comment: So basically i must create a custom validator which access the database and set it as a post validator in the form class.

Comment: Exactly. Just look at the links and do the same. (Or just use sfGuardPlugin!)